# $\sum a_n^2 <\infty$ implies $\sum a_n^3<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem :**

Given sequence $a_n$ s. t. $\sum_1^\infty (a_n)^2<\infty$.

Then $\sum_1^\infty(a_n)^3<\infty$ ?

---

Since $\sum a_n^2$ converge, $a_n \to 0$ where $n\to\infty$.

I tried to use two informations :

1. $a_n \to 0$
2. $a_n$ is bounded.

but It didn't make any hints.

I saw similar problems which determine convergence of $\sum a_n^k$
from $\sum a_n$ (or converse) but It was false.

(this means there is no relation between $a_n$ and $a_n^k$ in general.)

Is there any nice hints to approach this? or any counterexamples?

Comment: eventually, $|a_n|<1$ and so $|a_n^3|<|a_n^2|$ and so it's convergent.

Comment: Or, $\forall n: |a_n|\le A$ gives $|a_n^3|\le Aa_n^2$.

Comment: I think the "limit comparison test" is the cleanest way to go.  It's essentially @Farmer 's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since $a_n \to 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n| \leq 1$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} |a_n|^3 \leq \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} |a_n|^3 + \sum\limits_{n = N}^{\infty} |a_n|^2.$$
The first summand is finite and the second summand converges by assumption (assuming we are talking about real valued sequences here). Thus the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n^3$ is even absolutely convergent.

Comment: Should be $N-1$ as the upper limit for the first term on the right

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yep, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we set $b_n=|a_n^3|$. By $\sum a_n$ converge. Then we have

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = 0$ (by $\sum a_n$ converge).

Hence $\sum b_n$ converge and $\sum a_n^3$ converge.